# Confidence intervals in R Commander

Tags: r, regression, scatter-plot, confidence-interval, coefficients

I have some troubles when interpreting coefficients of confidence interval equations in R Commander. I obtained this scatterplot using ggplot2, where the gray background represents 95%CL of the fit model (blue line).

[image]

When obtaining the coefficients of the CL in R Commander, I get these results:

```
> Confint(RegModel.1, level=0.95)
             Estimate      2.5 %   97.5 %
(Intercept) 3.1383813 -0.3854986 6.662261
BL.mm       0.7571263  0.4316212 1.082631
```

As I can see, confidence equations (2.5% and 97.5%) seem to represent the typical straight line equations, when in fact, this impossible because they are curved. Actually, when I checked one random value for BL.mm and substituted on those equations, the limits of confidence don't fall in the limits of the gray area. What's wrong or what am I misundertanding?

UPDATE

This is the prediction interval of the same dataset:
[image]

So, the first picture represents exclusively 95%CI and not the prediction interval. So the first question remains unsolved.

Furthermore, when predicting the value of MD.mm when BL.mm in both prediction and confindence intervals is 10.25 mm...
[image]

... the results seem to be coherent with what is represented in the above picture.

```
> valorX=data.frame(BL.mm=10.25)

> predict(RegModel.2,valorX,interval="confidence",level=0.95)
       fit      lwr      upr
1 10.89893 10.58531 11.21255
> predict(RegModel.2,valorX,interval="prediction")
       fit     lwr      upr
1 10.89893 9.42737 12.370
```

48

So, why the equations of confidence interval are different from what would be expected?

Comment: The graph shows the confidence interval of predicted values, `confint` gives you the confidence interval of the model parameters. These are not the same and you can't calculate one from the other. Use the `predict` function to get the CI for predictions from a linear model.

Comment: [This post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85560/shape-of-confidence-interval-for-predicted-values-in-linear-regression) explains why the CI of predictions is curved.

Comment: Thanks to all. I have edited the original post in order to be more concise between confident and prediction intervals. I still need an answer...

Comment: I don't understand "So, why the equations of confidence interval are different from what would be expected?". You don't show any equations. And they are certainly not different from what is expected. You can derive these equations using maths.

Comment: What I mean is that using the coefficients of the equations that are below the first picture, which are supposed to be the equations of the 95CL and the fit model, the confidence interval when X = 10.25 (as shown in the updated version of the post) is not the same as using the predict function. Any idea?

Comment: Yes. Read my first comment.